# How do I install the cTAKES in eclipse IDE?

Tags: ctakes

I want to install the `cTAKES` in eclipse but did not find any proper documentation. I am following the documentation  of Apache software foundation
but I am not able to install `cTAKES`.
Please suggest any proper method to install.